# How do I use Latex/Tex-inspired keybindings in Dr. Racket?

Tags: racket

The [Racket Docs](https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/6.4/doc/drracket/Keyboard_Shortcuts.html#(part._.La.Te.X_and_.Te.X_inspired_keybindings)) say that to use a Latex/Tex-inspired keybinding like

`\Downarrow` for `⇓` that we should do something with `C-\ M-\ c:x;l`:

> C-\ M-\ c:x;l : traces backwards from the insertion point, looking for a backslash followed by a LaTeX macro name or a prefix of such a name. If a macro name is found, it replaces the backslash and the name with the corresponding key in the table below ...

The parts that confuse me are:

- What does `C-\ M-\ c:x;l` mean? I suspect the `C-\ M-\ c:x;l` is Ctrl, followed by Option, followed by something.
- I'm not sure I follow the business about tracing backwards. If I have my hands on the keyboard and I want to type an arrow, what do I actually do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the documentation you refer to is showing three likely bindings, but the DrRacket docs say that the final word on keybindings is to be found by consulting the *Show Active Keybindings* menu item from the *Edit* menu. When I check *Show Active Keybindings* on my DrRacket installation, I see as one of the options: `TeX compress (~c:m:\)`, which is equivalent to `M-\`, i.e., pressing <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> together. Entering `\Downarrow` followed by <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> in the interactions area, I am greeted with the expected character: `⇓`.

Comment: On Mac, typing \Downarrow and then Ctrl-\ works for me, but Option-\ does not, even though I'm using Option as Meta.

Comment: What does `(~c:m:\)` mean?

Comment: (~c:m:) is the [input state part of a _keyname_](https://download.racket-lang.org/releases/6.4/doc/gui/keymap_.html#%28meth._%28%28%28lib._mred%2Fmain..rkt%29._keymap~25%29._map-function%29%29), and it means that this keyname corresponds to pressing `Meta` without pressing `Ctrl`. My DrRacket installation shows both (~c:m:\\) and (c:~m:\\) as mappings for `Tex compress`, i.e. both M-\ and C-\, but c:\ (i.e. C-\\) is also bound to `Insert λ`, so I have to use M-\ for `Tex compress`.